# how can i play video encrypted with MP4box

Tags: xml, video, encryption

I'm trying to play a video that I've CENC-encrypted using MP4box with these options。

1. mp4box -crypt test.xml 1.mp4 -out clear.mp4

here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GPACDRM type="CENC AES-CTR">
<!-- example for GPAC 'clear' DRM System - keys are listed after the content and UL follows -->
<DRMInfo type="pssh" version="1" cypherOffset="9" cypherKey="0x6770616363656E6364726D746F6F6C31" cypherIV="0x00000000000000000000000000000001">
<BS ID128="6770616363656E6364726D746F6F6C31"/>
<BS value="2" bits="32"/>
<BS ID128="0x279926496a7f5d25da69f2b3b2799a7f"/>
<BS ID128="0x676cb88f302d10227992649885984045"/>
<BS bits="8" string="CID=Toto"/>
<BS ID128="0xccc0f2b3b279926496a7f5d25da692f6"/>
<BS ID128="0xccc0f2b3b279926496a7f5d25da692d6"/>
</DRMInfo>
<CrypTrack trackID="1" IsEncrypted="1" IV_size="16" first_IV="0x0a610676cb88f302d10ac8bc66e039ed" saiSavedBox="senc">
<key KID="0x202122232425262728292a2b2c2d2e2f" value="0x15161718191a1b1c1d1e1f2021222324"/>
</CrypTrack>
<CrypTrack trackID="2" IsEncrypted="1" IV_size="16" first_IV="0x0a610676cb88f302d10ac8bc66e039ed" saiSavedBox="senc">
<key KID="0x12131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f2021" value="0x25262728292a2b2c2d2e2f3031323334"/>
</CrypTrack>
</GPACDRM>
```

But, How can i play it  without decrypting it.
Just play it with this xml?
Please Help me, thank you very much。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPAC contributor here. Please note that we prefer that you use github issues.

Your XML file is wrong. You provide KIDs "0x279926496a7f5d25da69f2b3b2799a7f" and "0x676cb88f302d10227992649885984045" for the DRM scheme. But then KIDs for track encryption are unrelated.

The correct XML in your case is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GPACDRM type="CENC AES-CTR">
<!-- example for GPAC 'clear' DRM System - keys are listed after the content and UL follows -->
<DRMInfo type="pssh" version="1" cypherOffset="9" cypherKey="0x6770616363656E6364726D746F6F6C31" cypherIV="0x00000000000000000000000000000001">
<BS ID128="6770616363656E6364726D746F6F6C31"/>
<BS value="2" bits="32"/>
<BS ID128="0x279926496a7f5d25da69f2b3b2799a7f"/>
<BS ID128="0x676cb88f302d10227992649885984045"/>
<BS bits="8" string="CID=Toto"/>
<BS ID128="0xccc0f2b3b279926496a7f5d25da692f6"/>
<BS ID128="0xccc0f2b3b279926496a7f5d25da692d6"/>
</DRMInfo>
<CrypTrack trackID="1" IsEncrypted="1" IV_size="16" first_IV="0x0a610676cb88f302d10ac8bc66e039ed" saiSavedBox="senc">
<key KID="0x279926496a7f5d25da69f2b3b2799a7f" value="0xccc0f2b3b279926496a7f5d25da692f6"/>
<key KID="0x676cb88f302d10227992649885984045" value="0xccc0f2b3b279926496a7f5d25da692d6"/>
</CrypTrack>
</GPACDRM>
```

You can then play this the GPAC MP4Client player:

```
MP4Client encrypted.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you very much! may i ask you another quession ? How can i play it on html?  need your help ,thank you very much.

Comment: There is a feature request to implement W3C Clearkey in GPAC: https://github.com/gpac/gpac/issues/239 . Please show your interest there!